# What are Azure Resource locks?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

So to my understanding the delete lock doesn’t allow you to delete any resource correct? And the read only lock is basically allowing the user view only access. So is the read only lock the same thing as if I assigned the user reader permissions on the resource also?

Comment: check existing answers, to add to them, locks dont give permissions, they restrict access to operations your regular permissions would have granted you otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is pretty much correct. There is however a slight difference between giving a user reader permissions vs applying a read-only lock. A reader user cannot force his way to make changes / delete resources. An owner can still (potentially temporarily) remove a lock, apply the changes an reapply the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to the answer provided by NillsF.

Basically locks prevent accidental updates and deletes. When a user is in `Reader` role, whether a resource is locked or not, that user can't update or delete a resource.

However locks become important when the RBAC role allows a user to make an update or delete (e.g. a user in `Contributor` role).

If a resource is not locked, then that user can make updates and deletes if allowed by the role.

However if a resource is locked, then the user can't perform update/delete operation on a resource (in case a read-only lock is applied to the resource) or delete a resource (in case a delete lock is applied to the resource) even though their role certainly allow these operations.